# Hide All Columns except specified

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to find code which hides all specified columns for a report at work that I am slowly trying to automate. The report in question has 20 or so columns and I only really need 8 from the report.

I can easily use the code to write 12 or so lines to hide them. However it seems that it would easier to read and much more efficient to write the inverse of that code. I am fairly new to VBA and this is my first real project I can find use of the program for so far.

Current Project:

```
Sub Hide_Me()

Dim Lastcolumn As Long
Lastcolumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To Lastcolumn

If Cells(3, i).Value = "Customer Name" Or Cells(3, i).Value = "Address" Or Cells(3, i).Value = "Phone Number" or ... 'continue to perpetuity
Then Columns(i).Hidden = true

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Much simpler using `Select Case Cells(3, i).Value`, `Case "Customer Name", "Address",` etc..

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution. I've commented the code, so I hope you can understand it step by step. I'll apprectiate your feedback. :)

```
Sub Hide_Me()

    Dim rngHeadings As Range 'the range where your headings are
    Dim arrHideColumns() As Variant 'the array, where you list all headings that should be hidden
    Dim Item As Variant 'a common variable for the for-each-loop
    Dim rngResult As Range 'the range for the search result
    
'Assign the range, where your headings are

    Set rngHeadings = Worksheet1.Range("C3:E3")

'List the headings you want to be hidden

    arrHideColumns = Array("Address", "Phone Number")

'Loop through your list

    For Each Item In arrHideColumns
    
'Use the .FIND method of the range-object
'Please read more about this method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

        Set rngResult = rngHeadings.Find(Item)

'If there is a result

        If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then

'Hide the column

            rngResult.EntireColumn.Hidden = true
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```